# PHP -> SQL Query with Summing

Tags: php, query, wpdb, sql, plugin-gravity-forms

So I'm trying to display the sum of Paid Transactions for a customer's account:

```
SELECT SUM(`payment_amount`) 
FROM `wp_gf_entry` 
WHERE `created_by` = '2' 
AND `form_id` = '37' 
AND `payment_status` = 'Paid'
```

It works fine in SQL, but I am missing something in the PHP:

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_user_retainer', 'gform_populate_user_retainer');
function gform_populate_user_retainer($value){
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $user->ID;
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT SUM(payment_amount) as dviews FROM wp_gf_entry WHERE created_by = '$user_id' AND form_id = 37 AND payment_status = Paid");
  return $result->dviews;
}
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this, I see that "Paid", a string, isn't in quotes. That would cause an error. You can add [`$wpdb->show_errors()` and `$wpdb->print_error()` methods](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors) to reveal that, and any other mysql issues.

Also when querying the database, you should use the [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) method to escape and prepare your variables for query (yes `$user->ID` *probably* can't be compromised, but it looks like future values in that query might be replaced, or if that value was ever changed in the future to be from `$_REQUEST` -- it's just always good to escape).

I also used [`$wpdb->get_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable) instead of `$wpdb->get_results()` as it gives you the single value you're after which cleans things up a bit. And using `$wpdb->prefix` instead of `wp_` makes the plugin more compatible with other installs should this plugin/theme be released.

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_user_retainer', 'gform_populate_user_retainer');
function gform_populate_user_retainer($value){
    global $wpdb;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    // turn on errors
    $wpdb->show_errors();

    // make the query
    $result = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
        "
                SELECT SUM(`payment_amount`) as `dviews`
                FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}gf_entry` 
                WHERE `created_by` = %d
                AND `form_id` = 37 
                AND `payment_status` = 'Paid'
        ", 
        $user->ID
    ) );

    // if there was a query error
    if ( $wpdb->last_error !== '' ) {
        return " Error: " . $wpdb->print_error();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

If that doesn't fully solve your issue:

- If you returned `"hello world"` or `123` in `gform_populate_user_retainer()`, does the value appear where you expect? If it doesn't, is `gform_field_value_user_retainer` the correct hook?
- If you `echo "<pre>".$wpdb->prepare("..."); die();` the string query instead of running it, and pasted it into MySQL, does it work? If it doesn't follow the MySQL error to resolve.
- If you `echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);die();` the `$result` instead of returning it, do you see what you expect to return? If not, revise the query.
- If you `echo "<pre>"; print_r($user);die();` do you see what you expect? For yourself and other users? none-users?

Comment: Sorry for the late click.  Stackexchange wouldn't let me at first.  It took a few adjustments but I got the prepare() to work!